# Gitlab CI/CD Error failed to pull image "python 3.9" with specified policies [if-not-present]

Tags: python, docker, gitlab-ci-runner

I am new in devops and trying to pytest with Gitlab CI/CD and local docker runner.
My job failed with this error:

```
WARNING: Failed to pull image with policy "if-not-present": invalid reference format (manager.go:237:0s)
ERROR: Job failed: failed to pull image "python 3.9" with specified policies [if-not-present]: invalid reference format (manager.go:237:0s)
```

How can i fix it?

My .gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
  - test

image: python 3.9

run_tests:
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - pip install -r requirements.txt
  script:
    - pytest -v -s
  tags:
    - docker-local
```

My local runner.yml

```
services:
  runner:
    container_name: gitlab-runner
    image: gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest
    volumes:
      - ./runner/:/etc/gitlab-runner
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    restart: always
```

config.toml

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0
shutdown_timeout = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "test_runner_local"
  url = "https://my_url"
  id = 8
  token = "TOKEN"
  token_obtained_at = data
  token_expires_at = data
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    pull_policy = ["if-not-present"]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "python:3.9"
    privileged = false
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
```

If I delete the pull_policy field in config.toml or replace the value with 'always' - the error does not go away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You miss the colon, try this:

```
stages:
  - test

image: python:3.9  # you miss ":" 

run_tests:
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - pip install -r requirements.txt
  script:
    - pytest -v -s
  tags:
    - docker-local
```

Besides, there is free quota for CI/CD on gitlab.com . You can test whether your job works fine online, then test it at local, may save you a little debug time.

Comment: Thank you, you saved my day. And sorry for this question because of my inattention)

Answer (score 1):

try with

```
pull_policy = "if-not-present"
```

like in examples here
https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html#configure-how-runners-pull-images

Comment: Thank you for answer, but error was in missing ":" in docker-compose.yml